# Assign a random id to each element of 2d list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a 2D list

```
paths = [["root", "folderA", "folderB", "folderC", "folderD"], ["root", "folderA", "folderB", "folderE"]]
```

Which represents a tree structure like the following:

```
root
----A (1) 
--------B (2) 
------------C (3) 
----------------D (4) 
------------E (5)
```

I want to assign a unique ID to each folder (order doesn't matter).

However, the folder names can overlap. So, two folders that are not on the same level can have the same name. Like A and E can have the same name but not C and E.

I wrote this up:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d))
ids = [[d[y] for y in x] for x in paths]
```

However, this assigns identical ids to identical folder names.
Can someone help me think of any other smart way to do this given my naming condition?

Comment: You can use ``uuid`` for generating unique ids, ```from uuid import uuid4; ids = [[str(uuid4()) for y in x] for x in paths]```

Comment: maybe folder_name and it's parent folder name ?

Comment: @Sushanth that generates a unique id for each item in the list but that's not what I want :/

Answer (score 1):

Make entire path part of the name:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d))
ids = [[d[x[:i]] for i in range(1,len(x))] for x in paths]
```

Comment: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` ..... tuples would work bettter in this case I guess, since string concatenation leaves place to ambiguity.